How to do Silent Printing in Blazor hybird
I am working on the POS hybrid desktop application using blazor hybrid with .net maui. I want to print silently without showing the print dailog. So the application start printing with the default printer connected to the machine.
I tried JS print() function it but it shows printer dailog box which I don't want. I had also tried C# PrintDocument class which works fine, but it is only supported on Windows not for MAC.

Since the PrintDocument only supports windows, you can open a feature request:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/new/choose on Github or you can try this workaround.
